# Is it possible to let a client's PC that visits my site, visit an external URL and send the response of that URL back to me site?

Tags: php

And with that I don't mean AJAX, since this will be done from the server side right? I mean that the URL would be visited from the client's PC.

So step by step it would be something like this :

1. Client visits my site
2. My site orders the Client's PC to visit a URL
3. The client's PC visits this URL (perhaps doing this in the background)
4. The Client's PC sends the response it gets from this URL back to my server

I am also curious if there is a name for this kind of task. With that name I would be able to google this myself as well.

Comment: Google "CORS" - cross-origin resource-sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Doing this client-side with JavaScript and Ajax is as close as you are likely to get (and this will probably be blocked by the Same Origin Policy).

Comment: Would this also be blocked if the URL is a local IP? (I need this to acces my own router)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068 for the nitty gritty of when something is blocked and what the work arounds are.